# Different buttons with unique text, 1 clickfunction. How do I make it work to reduce my code?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two different buttons with different texts and I want to use a single clickedfunction and get the info/text from that particular button that they clicked.

This is my code so far:

```
String myString; //creating a string so I can store the texts on the same string.

myString = Button1.Text; 
myString = Button2.Text;  

Button1.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;
Button2.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;

void OnButtonClicked (object s, EventArgs e)
    {   
        myString = s as TextCell; //I want that the myString to now get the value depending on the clicked button. I am trying to do something with "text".
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object will most likely be the button that was clicked therefore you need to cast the sender object to Button and extract the Text of that button

```
void OnButtonClicked(object s, EventArgs e)
{
  Button btn=(Button)s;
  myString = btn.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot :) Easier than I thought.